# Issues with SCP

Tags: 12.04, command-line, scp

I am having problems with my `scp` command on Ubuntu 12.04. I can't SCP anything to my AWS server with Ubuntu 13.10. The terminal tells me that I am `scp: /index.html: permission denied`. What am I doing wrong?

My command

```
scp -v -i tyler.pem /BoT-Production/static/index.html ubuntu@{ip.add.re.ss`}:/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal users on the system do not have permissions to write to the root (`/`) directory of the file system. You should not be placing files in that directory anyway. You need to place the file in the `DocumentRoot` of your web server, for it to be found and visible when accessing the host through a web browser.